# Trying to concatenate a function and a value in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have this:

```
=MATCH('Plot Data - RAF'!B171,'MA Base'!J:J,0)
```

That gives me the row on a sheet where a certain string matches.  The result is 88.  I want to use that 88 in this function.

```
=INDEX('MA Base'!$K$88:$AN$88,1,MATCH(AS4,'MA Base'!$K$10:$AN$10,0))
```

Something like this:

```
=INDEX('MA Base'!$K$"& 88 &":$AN$"& 88 &",1,MATCH(AS4,'MA Base'!$K$10:$AN$10,0))
```

I can do it in VBA but I'm not sure if it's possible just by concatenating a string into a function.  Basically, I don't want to use VBA for this.

Comment: Index already takes that: `=INDEX('MA Base'!$K:$AN,MATCH('Plot Data - RAF'!B171,'MA Base'!J:J,0),MATCH(AS4,'MA Base'!$K$10:$AN$10,0))`  Index is set up like INDEX(LookupRange,Row,Column)

Comment: You are pretty close; certainly on the right track. I'm just finding it difficult to peel off the good from what needs improvement in that formula. Sample data would help.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  But is there a way ton concatenate a function or not?

Comment: Yes using the [indirect()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function but that is not advisable if there is a better solution.  Indirect is a [volatile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx). so your function would be `=INDEX(indirect("'MA Base'!$K$" & MATCH('Plot Data - RAF'!B171,'MA Base'!J:J,0) & ":$AN$" & MATCH('Plot Data - RAF'!B171,'MA Base'!J:J,0)),1,MATCH(AS4,'MA Base'!$K$10:$AN$10,0))`

Comment: Awesome!  Indirect is just what I was looking for.  One more question.  I have 'MA Base' in cell B173.  I'd like to reference that cell value rather than have it hard-coded.  How can I do that?

Comment: then something like this `INDIRECT("'" & B173 & "'!...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use INDIRECT() as suggested, but I would build a nested index and use the ability of index() to find both column and row.

The very thing you suggest:

```
=INDEX('MA Base'!$K$"& 88 &":$AN$"& 88 &",1,MATCH(AS4,'MA Base'!$K$10:$AN$10,0))
```

is better written like this:

```
=INDEX('MA Base'!$K:$AN,88,MATCH(AS4,'MA Base'!$K$10:$AN$10,0))
```

Now it is just a matter of creating that "88" in the same formula. Thus:

```
=INDEX('MA Base'!$K:$AN,MATCH('Plot Data - RAF'!B171,'MA Base'!J:J,0),MATCH(AS4,'MA Base'!$K$10:$AN$10,0))
```

In this index is first your (k:an) array, then a index for the row number you are looking for (that returns 88), then your column reference at row 10.